# Iterating over dataset using GSON parser

Tags: java, gson

I am writing a GSON (Java) parser for the CORD19 dataset
https://pages.semanticscholar.org/coronavirus-research of about 40K scientific papers which have been made open for everyone. I want to iterate over the JSON tree using GSON and convert them to HTML. In particular I want to iterate over the entries of the JsonObject elements.

Q1: If anyone has already written an F/OSS CORD19 parser in GSON or other Java parser I'd be delighted.

My specific problem is to iterate over the fields (entries) of a JsonObject.

Data (heavily snipped, but hopefully parsable if snips removed):

```
{
    "paper_id": "b801b7f92cff2155d98f0e3404229c67b60e2f9f",
    "metadata": {
        "title": "Realtime 2-5A kinetics suggests interferons \u03b2 and \uf06c evade global arrest of translation by RNase L",
        "authors": [
            {
                "first": "Alisha",
                "middle": [],
                "last": "Chitrakar",
                "suffix": "",
                "affiliation": {},
                "email": ""
            },
            ... SNIPPED
            {
                "first": "Alexei",
                "middle": [],
                "last": "Korennykh",
                "suffix": "",
                "affiliation": {},
                "email": "akorenny@princeton.edu"
            }
        ]
    },
    "abstract": [
        {
            "text": "Cells of all mammals recognize double-stranded RNA (dsRNA) as a foreign material. ...",
            "cite_spans": [],
            "ref_spans": [],
            "section": "Abstract"
        },
... SNIPPED
        {
            "text": "The 2-5A system is also a surveillance pathway for ...",
            "cite_spans": [],
            "ref_spans": [],
            "section": "Abstract"
        }
    ],
    "body_text": [
        {
            "text": "Interferons IFNs of type I (\uf061 and \u03b2) and type III ...",
            "cite_spans": [],
            "ref_spans": [],
            "section": "Introduction"
        },
        {
            "text": "To evaluate how the nuclear envelope ...",
            "cite_spans": [
                {
                    "start": 382,
                    "end": 384,
                    "text": "50",
                    "ref_id": null
                }
            ],
            "ref_spans": [],
            "section": "Diffusion calculations"
        }
    ],
    "bib_entries": {
        "BIBREF0": {
            "ref_id": "b0",
            "title": "Higher-order substrate recognition of eIF2alpha by the RNA-dependent protein kinase PKR",
            "authors": [
                {
                    "first": "A",
                    "middle": [
                        "C"
                    ],
                    "last": "Dar",
                    "suffix": ""
                },
... SNIPPED
                {
                    "first": "F",
                    "middle": [],
                    "last": "Sicheri",
                    "suffix": ""
                }
            ],
            "year": 2005,
            "venue": "Cell",
            "volume": "122",
            "issn": "",
            "pages": "887--900",
            "other_ids": {}
        },
        "BIBREF1": {
            "ref_id": "b1",
            "title": "Increased nuclease activity in cells treated with pppA2'p5'A2'p5' A",
            "authors": [
                {
                    "first": "A",
                    "middle": [
                        "G"
                    ],
                    "last": "Hovanessian",
                    "suffix": ""
                },
                ... SNIPPED
                {
                    "first": "L",
                    "middle": [],
                    "last": "Montagnier",
                    "suffix": ""
                }
            ],
            "year": 1979,
            "venue": "Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A",
            "volume": "76",
            "issn": "",
            "pages": "3261--3266",
            "other_ids": {}
        },
        "BIBREF2": {
            "ref_id": "b2",
            "title": "Interferon action--sequence specificity of the ppp(A2'p)nA-dependent ribonuclease",
            "authors": [
                {
                    "first": "D",
                    "middle": [
                        "H"
                    ],
                    "last": "Wreschner",
                    "suffix": ""
                },
                ... SNIPPED
                {
                    "first": "I",
                    "middle": [
                        "M"
                    ],
                    "last": "Kerr",
                    "suffix": ""
                }
            ],
            "year": 1981,
            "venue": "Nature",
            "volume": "289",
            "issn": "",
            "pages": "414--421",
            "other_ids": {}
        },
        ... SNIPPED
        "BIBREF47": {
            "ref_id": "b47",
            "title": "Size-dependent DNA mobility in cytoplasm and nucleus",
            "authors": [
                {
                    "first": "G",
                    "middle": [
                        "L"
                    ],
                    "last": "Lukacs",
                    "suffix": ""
                }
            ],
            "year": 2000,
            "venue": "J Biol Chem",
            "volume": "275",
            "issn": "",
            "pages": "1625--1634",
            "other_ids": {}
        },
        "BIBREF48": {
            "ref_id": "b48",
            "title": "Modeling transmembrane transport through cell membrane wounds created by acoustic cavitation",
            "authors": [
                {
                    "first": "V",
                    "middle": [],
                    "last": "Zarnitsyn",
                    "suffix": ""
                },
                ... SNIPPED
                {
                    "first": "M",
                    "middle": [
                        "R"
                    ],
                    "last": "Prausnitz",
                    "suffix": ""
                }
            ],
            "year": 2008,
            "venue": "Biophys J",
            "volume": "95",
            "issn": "",
            "pages": "4124--4162",
            "other_ids": {}
        }
    },
    ... SNIPPED
    "back_matter": [
        {
            "text": "We are grateful to Prof. Bonnie Bassler (Princeton University) for All NS All NS NS ** All ****",
            "cite_spans": [],
            "ref_spans": [],
            "section": "Acknowledgments:"
        }
    ]
}
```

There is a schema on the CORD-19 site, but entries such as `BIBREF1 ... BIBREF48` vary in number over each data set.
(Q what is the precise name for a `BIBREF` object - entry? Child?)

My current code is:

```
    @Test
    public void testReadJSON() {

        File jsonFile = new File(BIORXIV_MEDRXIV, "b801b7f92cff2155d98f0e3404229c67b60e2f9f.json");
        JsonObject oo = null;
        try {
            String resultsJsonString = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(jsonFile), "UTF-8");
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            oo = (JsonObject) parser.parse(resultsJsonString);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot read CORD19 file: "+jsonFile, e);
        }

        String paperId = oo.get("paper_id").getAsString();
        System.out.println("id: "+paperId);

        JsonElement metadata = oo.get("metadata");
        JsonObject metadataObject = metadata.getAsJsonObject();
        String title = metadataObject.get("title").getAsString();
        System.out.println("title: "+title);

        JsonElement authorsObject = metadataObject.get("authors");
        System.out.println("Auth: "+authorsObject);
        JsonArray authors = authorsObject.getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < authors.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(authors.get(i));
        }

        JsonElement abstrakt = oo.get("abstract");
        System.out.println("abstract: "+abstrakt);
        JsonArray texts = abstrakt.getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(texts.get(i));
        }

        JsonElement bodyText = oo.get("body_text");
        System.out.println("bodyText: "+bodyText);
        texts = bodyText.getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(texts.get(i));
        }

        JsonElement bibEntries = oo.get("bib_entries");
        System.out.println("bibEntries: "+bibEntries.getClass()+bibEntries);
        JsonObject obj = bibEntries.getAsJsonObject();
        // WHAT TO WRITE HERE?

    }

}
```

(Additional Q. I am learning Java8 so would appreciate answers in Java8 streams as well as Java7)

(Additional Q.
[I would not normally "advertise" on Stack Overflow, but these are not normal times, and think this will help save lives, and provide opportunities for Stack Overflow members to contribute skills]
I have set up volunteer projects to hack this dataset. I have had many years of extracting knowledge from scientific papers and believe that the existing papers may contain valuable pointers to new scientific knowledge.

- A GitHub project at https://github.com/petermr/openVirus
- A Wikimedia project at https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/WikiJournal_Preprints/Aggregation_of_scholarly_publications_and_extracted_knowledge_on_COVID19_and_epidemics using Wikidata to annotate articles.

Also - does Stack Overflow have a way of collecting expertise that can be re-used specifically for COVID-19?

Comment: This question got downvoted. I don't care about rep but it's a bit depressing when it's aimed at creating software and knowledge to save lives in the crisis.

Comment: Unfortunately that was expected (as were the 2 close votes so far). Even though some meta posts may claim different, StackOverflow is far from a *community*. It's a weird combination of an efficiency seeking QA platform with gamification (points, "funny hats") looking to provide value for shareholders, but still attempting to look like a free spirited community for developers & al. Not going for a rant here, just saying that gathering volunteers and broad questions won't fare well here, regardless of any humanitarian crises... can't recommend a better place though, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSON's [JsonObject](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) offers the `entrySet()` method for iterating the contents.

```
for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : obj.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();     // BIBREF0
    JsonElement value = entry.getValue();   // details, can be cast to JsonObject
    processBibRef((JsonObject)value);       // For example
}
```

Streams won't help much here, but separate methods for subelements should be used to structure the code better, as in the example.

As can be seen, manually parsing JSON is cumbersome with Java, and when you're transforming JSON to for example HTML, the extra step of converting to objects makes other less typesafe languages such as Javascript more attractive.

Comment: thanks. will try it. I already have my own library of semantic HTML objects so will stick with Java.

Comment: This is an accepted answer to the main question and the WHAT TO WRITE HERE. Thanks